The subcaptions are offeset slightly
I am trying to put 8 images in 2 rows and 4 columns, with the caption in-between the rows. For some reason, the captions are offset. How do I solve the problem?
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\subfloat[Baseline]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{Images/Feature Maps/Baseline_P_avg.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat[ProtoNet]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{Images/Feature Maps/ProtoNet_P_avg.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat[MatchingNet]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{Images/Feature Maps/MatchingNet_P_avg.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat[Reptile]{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{black.png}}}

\subfloat{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{black.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{Images/Feature Maps/ProtoNet_S_avg.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{Images/Feature Maps/MatchingNet_S_avg.png}}}
\hfill
\subfloat{{\includegraphics[width=0.22\textwidth]{black.png}}}    
\caption{graphs}%
\end{figure}

This is the output image it produces:


One solution using minipage.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Baseline}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{ProtoNet}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{MatchingNet}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Reptile}
\end{minipage}

\vspace{0.5cm} % Space between rows

\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{Another}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \subcaption{Option}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \subcaption{Case}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.22\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \subcaption{Solution}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Graphs}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


